# Subview's sublayers overlapping higher subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an issue: I'm creating a `UIView` that is returned from a method, and that part is fine, but what I've noticed is that when I add sublayers to one of the subviews, those layers overlap subviews that are higher up in the hierarchy (textView and imageView) the sublayers added to `testViewCopy` are appearing over top of these subviews, and they aren't supposed to. I have no idea what's going on here to cause this.

Code:

```
- (void)makeShareImages
{
    UIView *shareView = [self shareView];

    UIView *testViewCopy = [shareView viewWithTag:0];

    NSUInteger currentIndex = 1;

    for (NSDictionary *sub in self.array)
    {
        NSArray *lastArray = [sub objectForKey:@"LastArray"];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in lastArray)
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                currentIndex ++;

                CircleLayer *layer = [[CircleLayer alloc]init];
                layer.portrait = [[dict objectForKey:@"Portrait"]boolValue];

                layer.frame = testViewCopy.bounds;

                [testViewCopy.layer addSublayer:layer];

                NSData *frameData = [self getSnapshotDataFromView:shareView];

                NSString *savePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%lu.png",somePath,(unsigned long)currentIndex];

                [frameData writeToFile:savePath options:0 error:nil];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (UIView *)shareView
{
    UIColor *bgColor = self.containerView.backgroundColor;

    CGSize size = self.containerView.bounds.size;

    UIView *viewToShare = [[UIView alloc]init];
    viewToShare.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    viewToShare.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    viewToShare.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UIView *testViewCopy = [[UIView alloc]init];
    testViewCopy.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    testViewCopy.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    testViewCopy.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    testViewCopy.tag = 0;

    UITextView *textViewCopy = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    textViewCopy.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textViewCopy.tag = 1;
    textViewCopy.textContainerInset = self.textView.textContainerInset;

    UIImageView *profileImageViewCopy = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 32, 32)];
    profileImageViewCopy.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    profileImageViewCopy.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    profileImageViewCopy.image = [self profileImage];
    profileImageViewCopy.tag = 2;
    profileImageViewCopy.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageViewCopy.frame.size.width / 2.0;

    viewToShare.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    testViewCopy.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.width);
    textViewCopy.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    NSAttributedString *attributedStringCopy = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.textView.attributedText];

    textViewCopy.attributedText = attributedStringCopy;

    [viewToShare addSubview:testViewCopy];
    [viewToShare addSubview:textViewCopy];
    [viewToShare addSubview:profileImageViewCopy];

    return viewToShare;
}

- (NSData *)getSnapshotDataFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *snapShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapShot);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is behaving correctly. All sibling views - subviews of a common superview - have a definite layering order, back to front. `addSubview:` adds the subview as the *last* among its siblings; thus, it is layered in front of all existing subviews of the same superview. If that isn't what you want, insert the subview at a further layer back from the front, or add it (at the front) and then move it further back in the layering order.

Moreover (and here I think we are getting closer to the particular phenomenon you have noticed), views are themselves just layers. Thus, the layering order of views is actually a subset of the layering order of layers. The same thing I just said about views is equally true of layers, because views *are* layers: if you add a sublayer to a superlayer, it is added in front of all other sublayers of that superlayer, *including any subviews* if that superlayer is actually a view.

As I write in the current edition of my book:

> A view's subview's underlying layer is a sublayer of that view's underlaying layer, just like any other sublayers of that view's underlying layer. Therefore, it can be positioned anywhere among them in the drawing order. The fact that a view can be interspersed among the sublayers of its superview's underlying layer is surprising to beginners.

[image]

It sounds like you've just discovered this, and are appropriately surprised.

It may help to think of it in terms of the drawing of the render tree, in active terms. In other words, instead of thinking about how things *look*, think about what iOS *does*. A layer can have a superlayer, except for the ultimate superlayer, and a layer can have a previous sibling, except for the first sublayer of a superlayer. Conversely, a layer can have sublayers and it can have next siblings. We start by drawing the ultimate superlayer (the window). Then, for every layer we have just drawn, follow these two rules in order:

- Draw its first sublayer, if any.
- Draw its next sibling, if any.

Every time we draw a layer, it is in front of *everything* we have previously drawn. Thus all sublayers of a superlayer appear in front of the superlayer, and all later siblings (and their sublayers) appear in front of all previous siblings (and their sublayers). This results in what you see on the screen.

(However, note that you have even more flexibility, because among siblings you can manipulate the drawing order without rearranging the siblings, by setting the `zPosition` property of a layer.)

Comment: Please see my updated question, I discovered the subviews are in the correct order. The problem is that the layer's added to one of the subviews lower in the hierarchy overlap higher up views.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "lower in the hierarchy". And you give no information about your existing view hierarchy; your question is vague in the extreme. However, I have described to you the way it works. If what you are seeing is not what you are expecting, I can only suggest that you do not understand layering order or that you do not actually know the layering order of the views and layers in your hierarchy.

Comment: I just told you. Adding sublayers to a lower in the hierarchy subview shouldn't overlap a higher up in the hierarchy subview. I do not mean subviews, but rather sublayers.

Comment: OK, I'll add that to my answer. Hang on a second.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I've read your updated answer, but I'm not adding sublayers to the shareView (superview), I'm adding them to an individual subview directly (testViewCopy), so why would it overlap?

Comment: So how do I solve it then without bringing the subviews to front every time?

Comment: I don't know what "solve it" means because I don't know what you want to do. You are free to add sublayers to any superlayer, and you are free to move them forward or back in the layering order. You can put them wherever you want! So I don't see what the problem is. You can do anything you want to - except that you cannot violate the correlation between the structure of the layer hierarchy and the drawing order, since they are identical.

Comment: You can also manipulate the z-order as a way of violating the default drawing order among siblings. Would that help? Again, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_manipulating_the_layer_hierarchy