# GradientLayer is overlapping on cell label in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I want to change my cell label background to gradient and label text to white. The below image is the tableView and the cell label is overlapping as shown.

[image]

Here is my codes below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "tableViewCell",
            for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
  let bubbleGradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

  let colorTop = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0).cgColor
  let colorBottom = UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0).cgColor

  bubbleGradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
  bubbleGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
  bubbleGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

  bubbleGradient.frame = cell.text.bounds
  bubbleGradient.cornerRadius = 10
  cell.text.layer.addSublayer(bubbleGradient)
  cell.text?.text = text as? String

  return cell
}
```

But the GradientLayer is overlapping upon my cell label. How do I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subview's sublayers overlapping higher subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950670/subviews-sublayers-overlapping-higher-subviews)

Comment: can you share the code where you are adding this gradientLayer to cell`s label??

Comment: Inside this `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` @Kamran

Comment: @SeizeDuh can you paste all the `cellForRowAt` code? Meanwhile replace this line `cell.text.layer.addSublayer(bubbleGradient)` with `cell.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(bubbleGradient, at: 0)` to fix your issue.

Comment: Edited my codes @Kamran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert sublayer to UILabel it will hides label text. So, add UIlabel in UIView and apply gradient to UIView's layer. Check below code:

```
let bubbleGradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

let colorTop = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0).cgColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0).cgColor

bubbleGradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
bubbleGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
bubbleGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

bubbleGradient.frame = label.bounds
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
let viewLabel = UIView.init(frame: label.frame)
self.view.addSubview(viewLabel)
viewLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
viewLabel.addSubview(label)
bubbleGradient.cornerRadius = 10
viewLabel.layer.insertSublayer(bubbleGradient, at: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I just changed `bubbleGradient.frame = label.bounds
let viewLabel = UIView.init(frame: label.frame)` to `bubbleGradient.frame = cell.textLabel.bounds
            let viewLabel = UIView.init(frame: cell.textLabel.frame)`. Still not working

Comment: did you tried insertSublayer instead of addSublayer?

Comment: Make sure you have changed UILabel background color to clear color.

Comment: Edited with cellForRow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170370/discussion-between-ivarun-and-seize-duh).

Answer (score 0):

As you know, we reuse cell. In your code you are adding layer on view without removing the first layer. Which is creating problem.

```
    if cell.textLabel?.layer.sublayers == nil {

        let bubbleGradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let colorTop = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0).cgColor

        bubbleGradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        bubbleGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        bubbleGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        bubbleGradient.frame = (cell.text?.bounds)!
        bubbleGradient.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.text?.layer.addSublayer(bubbleGradient)
    }
```

Try this in your `cellForRow` method.

Comment: I just tried your code inside `cellForRow` but the whole if condition not being called

Comment: Have you added any other Gradient layer on text? please po `cell.text?.layer.sublayers` and check it.

Comment: Can you share design what do you want to do exactly?